# Convert variable to DateTime

Tags: php, date, variables

I want to display the difference between two dates. When I add the dates manually it works but when I try it with a variable it doesn't work.

This is the code so far:

```
$datum1 = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
$datum2 = new DateTime( date( $lid_geworden_op ));
$interval = $datum1->diff($datum2);
echo $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

When I echo `$lid_geworden_op` this is the output: `2017-07-01`

`$lid_geworden_op` is a custom field and stored like this in the database: `20170701`

For some reason I can't get the value of this variable in the DateTime...

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I put an ACF in a variable like this:

```
$lid_geworden_op = the_field( "lid_geworden_op" );
```

When I echo `$lid_geworden_op` I get as said before: `2017-07-01`

But when I var_dump($lid_geworden_op); I get NULL, seriously I dont know why...

**I feel realy stupid now... should be**

```
get_field( "lid_geworden_op" );
```

Thanks everyone for helping me out... and Sean, thanks for make me do the furder debugging... asked to soon.

Comment: Don't wrap it in date().  Date() expects a format not a date value.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($lid_geworden_op)`?

Comment: var_dump = object(DateTime)#9075 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-07-10 13:01:41.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }

Comment: If `$lid_geworden_op` is `NULL` (as mentioned in a comment to a deleted answer), then you are asking the wrong question. Figure out why `$lid_geworden_op` is `NULL`.

Comment: I realy dont know why but wil try to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in second line where `$datum2` is defined. Change it to:

```
$datum2 = new DateTime($lid_geworden_op);
```

Because [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function takes first parameter string (date format) and then second as timestamp.

Comment: I allready tried that, but still no luck. When I vardump $datum2 it gives me this: object(DateTime)#9074 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }

Comment: This is the same as `new DateTime($lid_geworden_op)`, just a much longer way of writing it.  DateTime already has a parser built into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_parse_from_format(string $format, string $date)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) function.

Steps:

1. Get Unix timestamp of the date `20170701`.
2. Convert this timestamp to date format `Y-m-d`.
3. Rest logic is already there.

   ```
   $datum1 = new DateTime( date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
   $parsed_date = date_parse_from_format('Ymd', $lid_geworden_op);
   $datnum2timestamp = mktime($parsed_date['year'], $parsed_date['month'], $parsed_date['day']);
   $datum2 = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d', $datnum2timestamp ));
   $interval = $datum1->diff($datum2);
   echo $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:
http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php

so you write:

```
$datum1 = new DateTime();
$datum2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', date( $lid_geworden_op ));
$interval = $datum1->diff($datum2);
echo $interval->y . " years, " . $interval->m." months, ".$interval->d." days ";
```

Because your Datum2 doesn't know your format, so you need to tell him how your date is displayed :)

Comment: `new DateTime('today')` for the same semantics as the original question